# Dictionaries in different lengths comparison in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to compare two dictionaries having different number of keys. For instance, here are two dictionaries:

```
person = {'name': 'John', 'birthYear': 1995, 'month': 1}
time = {'birthYear': 1995, 'month': 1}
```

I want to write code that if the second(birthYear) and third(month) key in person matches the first(birthYear) and second(month) key in time, the program will print out the name for the person (or in comparison just call it true). Is there a way to do so? I am pretty new to Python.

Comment: Do you have any draft code for this issue ?

Comment: Dictionary keys are not ordered, so there is no "first" or "second" one of them either. You can compare the values by `person['birthYear'] == time['birthYear']`. (That being said, the length of dictionaries is irrelevant for most applications.)

Comment: Also, dictionnaries are hashmaps, you should not expect ordering. It was [only added in python 3.7](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html).

Comment: @Rolf they are now ordered in insertion order (see my comment above), but your point stands, dict are not mean to be used with ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```py
person = {'name': 'John', 'birthYear': 1995, 'month': 1}
time = {'birthYear': 1995, 'month': 1}
if all(person[key] == time[key] for key in ['birthYear', 'month']):
  print(person['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is: try

```
if person['birthYear'] == time['birthYear'] and person['month'] == time['month']:
    print(person['name'])
```

Just use an if statement to check both conditions and print the results if they both pass the test

you can also nest the conditional statements like this:

```
if person['birthYear'] == time['birthYear']:  # this must be true
    if person['month'] == time['month']:      # and this must be true
        print(person['name'])                 # for this to print
```